# Frame to scale with child elements instead of pre-defining Width and HeightRequest

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a pop-up window which is built in a Grid. I want my pop-up window to have rounded corners, Therefore I made a custom renderer for a Frame, which I then intend to encapsulate the Grid in, like so:

```
<local:MaterialFrame BackgroundColor="Red" WidthRequest="Auto" >
    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#1eaaf0" Padding="40">
                <local:IconView Source="ic_connect.png" Foreground="White" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" />
                <Label x:Name="TitleLabel" Style="{DynamicResource FontBold}" Font="26" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
         .......
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</local:MaterialFrame>
```

The problem is though, that the Frame scales to fill the entire view! I could set `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`to a predefined value. But really, what I want, is, similar to the Grid, to make it Auto, so that the child elements decide those values.

Is that achievable?

Comment: Can you provide a ScreenShot of what you have, and what you want? Not sure I follow, you want the grid to fit the Frame?

Comment: I want the frame to stick to my Grid - not just cover the entire screen, as it does now.

Comment: Then set ignore the WidthRequest and Set the vertical options Center and HorizontalOptions to Center